# How to detect JTextArea is used as a CellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, tablecellrenderer

In my code I want to enable/disable certain functionality based on the context JTextArea is placed.

For Example: If JTextArea is used as a CellRenderer I want to disable certain funcionality.

How can I detect, if a particular JTextArea component is used as CellRenderer or not?

Comment: You mean `TableCellRenderer` or `ListCellRenderer` or another thing

Comment: In Both CellRenderes.

Comment: Override `getTableCellRendererComponent` for example if you are extending `DefaultTableCellRenderer` call `Component c =super.getTableCellRendererComponent; if (c instanceof JTextArea)`